# Why 32 by 32 4 bit BMP cursor is not displaying?

Tags: cursor, delphi-prism, oxygene

Since I can't find ZoomIn and/or ZoomOut magnifying glass cursor for my program, I created my own cursor of size 32 by 32 4bit with my compiler. However, when I do assign it to my form cursor, it is not displayed at all, whereas 16 by 16 4bit BMP cursor is properly displayed as expected.

Am I missing something or is this size not allowed as of now or do I have to do something to make it work?

Here is how it is set:

```
Mainform.Cursor := new Cursor(baseDir+'\ZoomIn.Cur');
```

[image]

This is what I see after saving 32 by 32 cursor file in the windows explorer.

[image]

Normally, you should see tiny version of the cursor right next the cursor file name, but I see none.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: No details on how you're loading it, no code at all, and a statement that "it's not working". Hmmm... Why do I not think you'll get much of an answer here?

Comment: The [second note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.aspx) under `Remarks` says that the `Cursor` class only supports black and white colors.  Is that what you created?

Comment: @KenWhite yes only black and white color

Comment: I can load a cursor fine (from the old `CodeGear Shared\Images` folder) using `self.Cursor := new Cursor('E:\code\XHAIR1.CUR');` in the main form's `MainForm_Load` event, and it's 32x32 pixel file, so it's not the size, so the problem is in your cursor file's color depth. Is there a reason you're using 4-bit instead of 1-bit (which is all b&w needs)?

Comment: @KenWhite, no reason at all. It just opened up with that color depth. I think, you maybe right...Let me make that change and let you know.

Comment: Nope, it didn't make any difference. I did notice that as soon as I delete or clear 16 by 16 cur it won't display even though I have 32 by 32 cur file created.

Comment: Wait... "Delete or clear"? You didn't mention that, and it's not in your code. What are you doing to delete or clear the cursor?

Comment: Ummm, I either clear by using the eraser or right click on it and delete. Is that how you do it? Just as you see it in the image above, it opens up with 16 by 16 by default and anything else you add is added in the bottom.

Comment: I just created a new 32x32 image (left everything else at default) in GreenFish Icon Editor (GFIE). I then drew a big `X` in it, and saved it (File->Save As...) a Windows cursor file called `Dummy32x32.cur` in the same folder I mentioned above, changed my code to use it instead of `XHair1`, and ran the app. It worked fine (except that the big, ugly `X` was hard to use to click on the app's close button).

Comment: Well, I see what you are doing, Ken, but I am not using third-party tool but from within my compiler. Maybe I should give GreenFish Icon Editor a try before I look like a dummy :).

Comment: Your "compiler" does not have an image viewer or editor. Of course you mean from your "IDE" (Visual Studio). :-) When I do File->New File->Cursor File, it opens with a 32x32 1 bit image. I can do the same as above (draw an `Z` through it instead to make it look different, save it in the same folder as `Dummy32x32_2.cur`, change my code to use it by adding the `_2` to the filename, and run). It works perfectly, the same as the last one, with the only difference is that it displays `Z` instead of `X`.

Comment: Ken, it works, but it is inverted. Cursor itself is white and the whole cursor image is totally black. I did invert it in the GreenFish Icon Editor, but it still does it. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't do a lot of custom cursors any more, and when I was I used Resource Workshop (used to ship with Delphi). So the problem did turn out to be an issue with the color depth of your icon file?

Comment: It does look that way, Ken. With cursor file I created, all the transparent area looks black but see through and the cursor looks white.

Comment: Finally, got it working just the way I wanted....Thanks, Ken

Comment: Should I post an answer about the color depth, or do you want to just delete this question?

Comment: I think you should post an answer, Ken.

Comment: Done. I hope I covered it all. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows (at least the .NET `Cursor` class) doesn't appear to like icons that are more than 1-bit black and white images.

32x32 bit are still supported. I tested using one of the old `CodeGear Shared\Images\Cursors` images, as well as a new cursor created in GreenFish Icon Editor and in the Visual Studio Image Editor (File->New File->Cursor file), using the following code:

```
method MainForm.MainForm_Load(sender: System.Object; e: System.EventArgs);
begin
  self.Cursor := new Cursor('E:\code\XHAIR1.CUR');
end;
```

So reducing the color depth to 1-bit should make it work for you.